# SVN Commit issue: "PROPFIND request failed on <folderpath>" - folder is not in the repository OR working copy

Tags: svn

I haven't used SVN for all that long, but this one is puzzling me.

I'm trying to commit my working copy code, and I get an error:

> svn: PROPFIND request failed on *folderpath*
>
> svn: *folderpath* path not found

The *folderpath* is not present on the working copy or the repo.
In this case, the path named WAS in some previous version, but was deleted.

What's the best way to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the simplest way if you can not find the solution fast is to checkout fresh copy and bring all your changes manually. After that repeat commit.

Comment: A practical suggestion.  I might get to that point, but I'd really like to get some clues on why this could have happened so I can avoid it in the future.

Comment: After trying to research this, I ended up just taking this suggestion.  I did find, later, that somehow I had two folders at the same depth pointing to one folder on the repository.  Not sure how that happened, but after doing a fresh checkout and re-importing my changes, future commits are working fine.